# Polymer based Product Tour Component / Tutorial Component

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I am looking for a Polymer based Product Tour Library or Tutorial Component similar to https://bootstraptour.com/ or https://github.com/usablica/intro.js with the support of shadow-dom

I've found a project: https://github.com/aruntk/walk-tour
but the it seems to be old. The owner doesn't maintain it.

Thanks

Comment: So what is your Question? Shall we help using google or what do you need?

Comment: I was just interested if you have any experience in on of the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I've did some research and prototype and I've found 2 libs
https://introjs.com/
https://kamranahmed.info/driver.js/

Both of them are highly customizable, supports shadow dom selectors, and they don't have unnecessary dependencies like jquery.